# In Postgres, how do you extract the month (according to specific timezone) from a given TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

I have a column called `login_timestamp`, which is of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

To retrieve the month for this timestamp, I would do: `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM login_timestamp)`.

However, **I would like to retrieve the month for a specific time zone (in my case, Pakistan)**, but can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation for this is under [Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html). Search that page for "at time zone".

```
select extract(month from login_timestamp at time zone 'Asia/Karachi');
```

You can change the time zone for a single session or for a single transaction with `set session...` or `set local...`. For example, this changes the time zone for the current session.

```
set session time zone 'Asia/Karachi';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `AT TIME ZONE` construct:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM login_timestamp AT TIME ZONE '-5');
```

-5 is the constant offset for Pakistan.

Details:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `AT TIME ZONE`. Demo

```
select extract(month from cast ('2017-07-01 01:00+03' as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) AT TIME ZONE '+08') as monthNo
```

returns

```
    monthno
1   6
```